# Loop in VBA for get values in cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The user select a path for a file and click yes, each path file are inserted in a  worksheet(Column1).

I try to make a loop to read this path file in the worksheet(Column1) until the end of records

This is the code I try but do not work well  because when the path is ="" I get an error. So I want to quit the when the file path is =""(cell = "")

```
    Do Until Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3).Cells(cnt, 1).Value = Null

    fileName = Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3).Cells(cnt, 1).Value


    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(fileName) //If fileName="" I get error

    Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
        sText = sText & oFS.ReadLine
    Loop
    Debug.Print sText
    cnt = cnt + 1

RE6 sText, fileName

Loop
```

Thanks Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check for Trim$(Cell.Value) = "", rather than Null, on the first line?

Comment: Do Until Trim$(Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3).Cells(cnt, 1).Value) = ""

Comment: Do Until Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3).Cells(cnt, 1).Value = EmptySting Is the cleanest way thanks